# How can I change the heroes on my team?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I've been looking through menus, the FAQ, and online, but can't seem to figure out how to build a hero team.

I just finished chapter 1 and summoned 5 new heroes. However, I'm not seeing any way to assign them to the team I plan to use on a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit your teams, click on the "Allies" tab on the bottom of the screen. From there, you can select the "Edit Teams" button to pick who will be on a team. The arrows on the left and the right of the four character portraits will allow you to choose between preset teams (as 4 seems to be the maximum number of units you are allowed per battle).

It's worth noting that the same character can be used in multiple teams.

Comment: I hit that before getting heroes and totally thought it was a friends list.